# Multiple equally spaced arrows from one rectangle node to another rectangle node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to connect multiple arrows from one rectangle node to the other. I tried by having a few coordinate nodes declared in parallel and connecting these coordinate nodes together to form parallel arrows and then tried to place the rectangle node exactly on top of the coordinate list but I never succeded. My solution is as shown in the first picture.
[image: pic 1]
I am trying to do this
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To access selected positions of the node you can use the name of the node together with an angle separated by a dot, as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, text badly centered, text width=2cm,minimum size=1cm] (a) {Frequency synthesizer};
  \node[draw, text badly centered, text width=2cm,minimum size=1cm,below=of a] (b) {Code generator};
  \draw[->] (b.140) -- (a.220);
  \draw[->] (b.40) -- (a.320);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked like charm. Does tikz manual have the "angle separated by a dot" thing?

Comment: @Meeir Aalie: yes, at the end of Section 13.2.3 Node Coordinate System.