# bloc rectangle with several arrows as input with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I want this :

[image]

With arrows aligned and the possibility to add or remove some at the left or right sides. And the possibility to add labels at arrows extremities.
I try [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15183/multiple-equally-spaced-arrows-from-one-rectangle-node-to-another-rectangle-node) technique but it does not work well for my case.

EDIT 1: I tried this :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
  \node[draw, rectangle, minimum height=2cm, minimum width=2cm,align=center] (bloc) {};
  \node[rectangle, minimum height=2cm, minimum width=0cm, left of=bloc] (hide) {};
  \draw[->] (hide.40) -- (bloc.220) {};
  \draw[->] (hide) -- (bloc) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You can keep only `(bloc)` node and then use `\draw[->] ([xshift=-1cm]bloc.220) -- (bloc.220);` or simpler `\draw[<-] (bloc.220)-- +(-1,0);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think in a simple way.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2.5,2);
\draw[->] (2.5,1)--++(1,0);
\draw[<-] (0,.3)--++(-1,0);
\draw[<-] (0,.9)--++(-1,0);
\draw[<-] (0,1.2)--++(-1,0);
\draw[<-] (0,1.6)--++(-1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Shorter code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2.5,2);
\foreach \i in {1,1.3} % Add to this list
    \draw[->] (2.5,\i)--++(1,0);
\foreach \i in {.3,.9,1.2,1.6} % Add to this list
    \draw[<-] (0,\i)--++(-1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know how you want the labels to be, but this may be a start

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2.5,2);
\draw[->] (2.5,1)--++(1,0) node[right] {xyz};
\draw[<-] (0,.3)--++(-1,0) node[left] {mnp};
\draw[<-] (0,.9)--++(-1,0);
\draw[<-] (0,1.2)--++(-1,0) node[left] {abc};
\draw[<-] (0,1.6)--++(-1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Remember increasing the size of the picture in case the size of the label is too big.